# Java - Mac application requires JDK to be installed in order to run

Tags: java, macos, java-8, jar

I have a Java application that runs on Mac OS X (Bundled in a .app file) with 2 Jar files inside it. One Jar runs the other Jar to pass some variant parameters.
I've also embedded JRE with the application so the user needs not to worry about downloading Java at all. The problem is that when user runs the app,
the first Jar runs fine using the embedded JRE, but when it tries to run the second Jar through this sample code:

```
String jarPath = "MyMainJar.jar"
String [] cmd = { "java", "-jar", "-noverify", jarPath };
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

The following error always appears in Mac:
[image: Mac Java App requires JDK]

And in Terminal this is printed:
*No Java runtime present, requesting install.*

If i install JDK things will work just fine, but the main idea here is that i have embedded JRE so user won't worry about those Java issues and installing it.
**So my questions are:**

- My embedded JRE has the "java" tool in the "bin" folder. Why can't the first Jar use it? Why does it insist to have the JDK?
- Can i embed JDK instead of JRE with my app?
- Can i detect this issue in my code before the Mac OS message appears to the user so i could show a better message to him?
- Any other suggested solution to fix this without asking the user to install JDK on his Mac?

Comment: I assume the first jar runs because of some native script that directly invokes the embedded JRE's binaries? In that case, couldn't you just either provide a second script for the other jar, or if you have to use it from the first one, use it as a library? You could also try and run your process from a relative path to your embedded JRE (so the OS doesn't try to make the user install another one), but I have a feeling that's not the best idea...

Comment: Exactly. The Mac .app file has a script to run a Jar file which is my first Jar. I need to run Jar 2 from Jar 1 to pass many parameters to Jar 2 like the memory values to use: -Xms and -Xmx.

Comment: may I ask what version of Java?

Comment: It requires Java 1.8 at least ...

Comment: Perhaps, it resolves to a different `java` executable. Try with explicit path, i.e. `Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "java").toString()` instead of just `"java"`. And *don’t use `-noverify`*.

Comment: @Holger ... This has actually fixed it! :) ... Thanks a lot. Please add this as an answer so i could set it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `java` without an absolute path, there’s the possibility that resolving it through the system specific command search path ends up at an executable of a different java installation.

To enforce the use of the same JVM you’re already running on, resolve the command against the `java.home` system property.

```
String jarPath = "MyMainJar.jar";
String jarCmd = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "java").toString();
String [] cmd = { jarCmd, "-jar", jarPath };
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

As a side note, don’t use `-noverify`. The benefits of this options, in case there are some, do not justify its risks.

Also, if you don’t plan to feed constructed input to the new process or to parse its output, it’s worth chaining `.inheritIO()` to the `ProcessBuilder`, so the new process will use the same input/output channels as the parent process, instead of creating pipes.